# jQuery .click not picking up SVG elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I am trying to use jQuery to make a click event for an SVG rectangle.  It seems that jQuery isn't picking up any of my SVG elements or children, regardless of whether I use tags or Ids.  I am looking for the simplest solution to get this functionality.

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('rect').click(function(){
        alert('yeah')
        x = $(this).attr('x')
        y = 9 - $(this).attr('y')
        ws.send( JSON.stringify({'command': 'squareclicked', 'x': x, 'y': y}) )
    })
})
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <svg id="bigsvg">
        <g class="whitesquares">
            <rect width="1" ID="square18" y="1" x="1" height="1" />
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: alert displayed for me : http://jsfiddle.net/xP9YD/1/

Comment: What browser are you testing in?